# 1С УПП Долго проводится Расчет себестоимости

Tags: 1с

Я не разу не 1с програмист. Но мне попалась задачка - есть конфигурация **Управление производственным предприятием, редакция 1.3 (1.3.35.2)**. В ней бухгалтера создают документы  **Расчет себестоимости** (РасчетСебестоимостиВыпуска называется в конфе).
Жалуются что документ за декабрь проводится медленно ~20мин. А до этого вс работало быстро. Я сделал копию базы и попробовал проводить эти отчеты за октябрь, ноябрь и январь. Они выполнились менее чем за 10мин. А декабрьский действительно выполняется 20+мин. По умолчанию у документа 10 пунктов действий(которые он выполняет при провидении). Я стал убирать по одному и как только убрал **7.Распределение косвенных расходов по пределам** – он сразу начал проводиться за 3-5 минут. Полез в код. Внутри процедуры:

```
Процедура ВыполняемоеДействиеРаспределениеКосвенныхРасходовПоПеределам( 
    СтруктураШапкиДокумента,
    ДиректКостинг,
    СтруктураТаблицДвижений
    )
```

Есть такая запись:

```
ПроцедурыРасчетаСебестоимостиВыпуска.РаспределениеКосвенныхРасходов(
        СтруктураШапкиДокумента, 
        СтруктураТаблицДвижений, 
        ДиректКостинг, 
        Перечисления.СпособыРасчетаСебестоимостиПродукции.ПоПеределам
        );
```

Я замерил время ее выполнения и получил что в октябрьском отчете она выполняется за 170сек., а декабрьская аж 971 сек. 
Но мозгов понять что делается в этом блоке не хватает.
Подскажите куда копать? 
Я как понимаю но основании данных из шапки документа и действий из табличной части - он должен лезть еще в какие то процедуры чтобы посчитать дальше. Как мне обнаружить какие это процедуры что-бы засечь время из выполнения?

Comment: Судя по тому что вы "накопали" - у вас не плохо получается быть программистом 1С :)
С УПП лично дел не имел. Но если вы делали замеры средствами платформы (старт/стоп) - то результат можно просматривать по всему стеку вызовов.

Comment: К сожалению нет. Даже не слышал что у 1с есть свои средства для замеров. Но правда никогда особо и не интересовался. Я использовал довольно примитивный код с инфостата:                                                                НачалоОперации = ТекущаяУниверсальнаяДатаВМиллисекундах();         ...                  ЗаписьЖурналаРегистрации("СписаниеПоСредней, сек", УровеньЖурналаРегистрации.Предупреждение, , ,
        Формат((ТекущаяУниверсальнаяДатаВМиллисекундах() - НачалоОперации) / 1000, "ЧДЦ=3; ЧГ=0"));     Расскажите что за средство, я попробую м.б. это как раз то что мне нужно!

Comment: Не факт что речь идет о ошибке, т.к. в декабре он может закрывать весь год и т.п. Для более детальной проверки - сделайте следующее (по уже применяемому Вами способу) Установите точку останова в проблемной процедуре, запустите отчет, после останова в начале процедуры - в конфигураторе установите вторую точку останова в конце процедуры, нажмите замер производительности, F5 - продолжить выполнение, на второй точке останова Окончить замер; Проанализируйте 2 раза, вначале на ноябре затем на декабре.

Comment: Я загуглил средство замера производительности платформы о котором говорил Ascell. И прогнал тесты как вы мне советовали. Вышло что процедура ПроцедурыРасчетаСебестоимостиВыпуска.РаспределениеКосвенныхРасходов (второй кусок кода в моем вопросе). Выполняется в октябре  177 ед. измерения времени или 53% от общего. А в декабре 879 времени или 86%. Но не видно что именно она там считает. Не показывает стек глубже. Не подскажите как это сделать?